# Does Scooby-Doo know that he is a dog?

Tags: scooby-doo

This question occurred to me upon repeated viewings of *Scooby-Doo on Zombie Island*.

Several times in the movie, Scooby-Doo hears another character referring to a dog and seems to not know that *he's* the dog they're referring to. I realize this may be a simple recurring joke but this got me wondering, does Scooby-Doo know that he is a dog?

Here are the relevant lines from the movie:

> Simone Lenoir - Who brought this-this dog?
> Scooby-Doo - Dog? Where?

> Lena Dupree - But I'm afraid your dog will have to eat in the kitchen.
> Scooby-Doo - Dog? Where?

> Simone Lenoir - I've had enough of that meddling dog!
> Scooby-Doo - Dog? Where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unknown

Scooby and Shaggy are best friends and peers.  Scooby likely doesn't see himself as any different than Shaggy on some level, but certainly must recognize the difference exists when he looks at himself in a mirror (which has happened in several episodes), as well as the fact that Scooby Dum and Scrappy Doo looks nothing like Shaggy or Freddie.  However, within the cartoon's episodes and movies, it's never mentioned whether Scooby knows he's a dog.

In the references you mentioned, that was likely part of a running joke within the movie.